# How to render a texture on a triangle strip?

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

I'm creating an android side scrolling game using the libgdx library. I am using `immediateModeRenderer20` in `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` mode to render 2D triangle strips that scroll infinitely. The renderering works fine, I have figured out how to use solid colors, gradients and alternating patterns on the strip.

Is there any way to render a triangle strip but overlay it with a .png or a Texture or something like that?

I have looked into the `texCoord(...)` method in the `immediateModeRenderer20` [docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ImmediateModeRenderer20.html) but I haven't found any solid examples on how to use it.

If anyone needs any code snippets or images, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, I've recently attempted the same.

The loop for rendering it looks simply:

```
texture.bind();
immediateModeRenderer20.begin(camera().combined, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
immediateModeRenderer20.color(new Color(1, 1, 1, 1));
immediateModeRenderer20.texCoord(textureCoordinate.x, textureCoordinate.y);
immediateModeRenderer20.vertex(point.x, point.y, 0f);
immediateModeRenderer20.end();
```

But the important thing is that you build your texture coordinates to match your triangles. In my case I would draw a rope like this one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk6x6.jpg

from a texture of a straight rope. To texture each triangle you will need texture coordinates x and y - remember that textures use different coordinates: from 0.0 to 1.0 for both x and y.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9chiQ.jpg

So your triangle vertex will need textureCoord value of:

1. x: 0.0, y: 0.0
2. x: 0.0, y: 1.0
3. x: triangle length, y: 0.0
4. x: triangle length, y: 1.0

and so on.